# optical flow works for zooming in and zooming out

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, opticalflow

I was wondering if Optical flow algorithm can be used for zooms.
I have a video which has a clip of a webpage zooming in and zooming out.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~sharat/icvgip.org/ncvpripg2008/papers/9.pdf) shows that it can be. A web page zooming in and out sounds easier than natural images. But then, if the web page was displayed on a monitor and then captured with a video camera, screen flicker can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. According to the paper [Robust Camera Pan and Zoom Change Detection
Using Optical Flow](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~sharat/icvgip.org/ncvpripg2008/papers/9.pdf):

> Zoom-outand zoom-in are identified using the convergence and divergence
>   of flow vectors respectively.